# How to limit GPU/CPU use when baking, rendering etc?

Tags: rendering, baking

I want to limit my GPU and CPU use **only** in bakes, renders etc as precaution for overheating. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The nerd-name for what you want to do is *throttling*.  It's not something you should need to do on modern computers, because modern CPUs and GPUs are equipped with thermal monitors and modern operating systems run internal code to throttle the CPUS.

However, you can give your operating system guidance on how conservative to be in managing heat.  The problem, for your purpose, is that you can't make the guidance as targeted as "only this application, and only under these conditions."  Typically you can give it guidance like "when on battery do this".

Different operating systems have different mechanisms for providing this guidance, and it is outside the scope of a Blender question to describe it; but if you search the internet, the best search term is probably *power management*.

If you are having heat management problems, then its probably due to a driver bug in your OS or a failure in your hardware, such as clogged vents, improperly applied thermal paste or fan failure.  Again, how to deal with this is outside the scope of a Blender question.

Comment: Do I need to do anything for the GTX 1650 Ti?

Comment: You should not need to, beyond keeping the drivers up to date, no.  NVidia has been pretty aggressive about power management for decades.